# Highlight all elements in a div when the div is hovered

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to get all the elements to highlight in the li element once the li is hovered.

```
<ul class="category-box">
    <li>
         <h1><a>...</a></h1>
        <p class="meta">Lorem ipsom <a>...</a>
         <a>...</a>
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('.category-box li').hover(function () {
    $(this).css('color', '#a58637');
},
function () {
    $(this).css('color', 'black');
});
```

Comment: And what's the problem?  What isn't working about this?

Comment: @JamesMontagne - Specificity probably. Any defined styles closer than the list element will override the hover color.

Comment: @James Montagne i want all of the elements to light up once the li element is hovered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with straight up CSS

```
.category li, .category li * {
    color: black;
}

.category li:hover, .category li:hover * {
    color: #A58637;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For didactic porpuse, test it:

```
<style>
    .texthover {
        color: #ff0000 !important;
    }
    .textout {
        color: #000 !important;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("li").mouseover(function () {
            $(this).removeClass(".textout");
            $(this).addClass(".texthover");
        }).mouseout(function () {
            $(this).removeClass(".texthover");
            $(this).addClass(".textout");
        });
    });
</script>
```